# Building default wxWidgets project in Code::Blocks gives fatal error: iosfwd: No such file or directory message

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets, codeblocks

BASIC INFO:

OS = Windows 7 - 64 bit.
Code::Blocks installed using codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe
wxWidgets installed using wxMSW-3.0.2-Setup.exe

**New project created using the following options:**
    wxWidgets project
    wxWidgets 3.0.x
    Name: wxHelloWorld
    Preferred GUI builder: wxSmith
    Application type: Frame based
    wxWidgets' location: C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2
    Compiler: GNU GCC Complier
    **wxWidgets Library Settings (checked):**
        Use wxWidgets DLL
        wxWidgets is built as a monolithic library
        Enable unicode
        Configure Advanced Options
    **Debug Target:**
        GUI Mode Application
    **Release Target:**
        GUI Mode Application

From this point, I click on build and get the following Build messages:

File                        Line    Message
                            === Build: Debug in wxHelloWorld (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\include\wx\iosfwrap.h    17  fatal error: iosfwd: No such file or directory
                            preprocessing failed.
                            === Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===

The code displayed is:

```
#if wxUSE_STD_IOSTREAM

#if wxUSE_IOSTREAMH
    // There is no pre-ANSI iosfwd header so we include the full declarations.
#   include <iostream.h>
#else
#   include <iosfwd>
#endif

#ifdef __WINDOWS__
#   include "wx/msw/winundef.h"
#endif

#endif // wxUSE_STD_IOSTREAM
```

The file in question is in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++
**I have tried:**
    Under Settings/Compiler/Search directories: Compiler and Linker and Resource Compiler:
    Adding the above file path. This moved the problem to other 'missing' files in similar locations, which I remedied, and eventually lead to a syntax error...
I have also tried installing Code::Blocks directly in C:\ and also copying the MinGW 'include' folder (above) to C:\ (to remove spaces in the file path) this didn't help.
The source files are named wxHelloWorldApp.cpp and wxHelloWorldMain.cpp
Can anyone please advise what is wrong?

Comment: Instead of doing all of the installing and uninstallng, you shoud have first tried a very simple application that only did `#include <iosfwd>`.  If that can't compile cleanly, then you have a problem with your general compiler settings.  If it did build, then it is your wxWidgets throwing things off.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I created a 'Hello World' console app and included iosfwd and it compiled without complaint. The problem is definitely with wxWidgets.